# Adding ListItems in sharpoint bu workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i have two sites in my sharepoint namely "site1" and "site2" . i have one list namely "add items" in both site. when i add a item in site1 list the same items should be added in site list also . can anyone say me how to do this . when i used the designer for adding list items it shows only the list names of particular site .

Regards,
Zakeer Ahamed.S

Answer (score 1):

you can create an event listener for the list in site1. In which you will be adding item to list in site2 using the ItemAdded Event.

Answer (score 1):

With an out of the box workflow action you can't do that, you could write your own custom action for SPD to do that.

Also check out, might give you some ideas, even though its not a workflow:
[How to keep two SharePoint Lists in sync when located on 2 different servers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3862/how-to-keep-two-sharepoint-list-in-sync-when-located-in-2-different-servers)

From codeplex:
http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity

I haven't tried that one, but from the comments people seems to have it working on SP2010.