# Sharepoint server 2010 in DMZ

Tags: dmz

I have scenario where I have two sharepoint servers (SP Foundation 2010), one sits inside the internal network and second one sits in a DMZ.

Now, I have a task at hand to share a list's data between two SP Sites and keep them sync whenever any one of the list on any of those server gets updated.

Please share your answers.

Thanks RHM.

Comment: A more or less similar question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3862/how-to-keep-two-sharepoint-list-in-sync-when-located-in-2-different-servers (maybe you can find some ideas there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be implemented using the two alternatives:

I assume that you can access the [OOTB lists web service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sharepoint2010general/thread/2f4270dc-de48-4012-906b-aed7ea42bcab) to manipulate both the lists. So the next step is to attach the Event receivers to both the Lists i.e. List 1 and List 2.

For example you have these Event receivers on List 1:

1. ItemAdded (you can use this method and access the list 2 and add the same item there)
2. ItemUpdate (you can use this method and access the list 2 and update the same item there)
3. ItemDeleted (you can use this method and access the list 2 and delete the same item there)

The access between the two lists can be accomplished using the OOTB List Web service or Object Model.

The other option could be to create a custom timer job which sync the both list items. You can use hidden field to check which items have been sync during the timer job execution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Idea of using webservice sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft published a description of some [SharePoint Extranet Topologies](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24079); You could use the Back-to-back perimeter topology.

The advantage of this approach is that your content is all in one farm - you don't need to synchronize between different lists.

Comment: Let me check this